# Jquery toggleClass reduce image size on click

Tags: jquery, image, toggle, reduce, image-size

I have webpage where I can navigate with arrows horizontally. I would like to add an effect when you click on the arrows his size reduce of 10% and refind his normal size on the next slide. With hover it works but not with onclick. I prefer to use on click because I fear that hover which doesn't work on a tablet. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong in script ?

```
<a href="#1" title="next" class="flscroll" id="flscrolld"></a>
```

here my css :

```
#flscrolld {
        background: url(images/sprite2.png) no-repeat left -200px;
        padding-right: 50px;
        right: -30px;
        width: 53px;

        -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    }
    .transition {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.6); 
    -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
    -o-transform: scale(0.6);
    transform: scale(0.6);
}
```

My Jquery script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#flscrolld" ).click(function() {
        $("#flscrolld").toggleClass('transition');
    }, function() {
        $("#flscrolld").removeClass('transition');


    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`click` only has one callback, and `toggleClass` does exactly what it sounds like, it toggles the class, so you only need one callback

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#flscrolld" ).click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('transition');
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/93d54/)

Comment: Hi adeneo, thank you for your help. If I need that the arrow refind his normal size on the next slide, do I need to use something else than toggleClass ?

Comment: I have no idea what context you're using this in, or what the next slide even is, so it's hard to tell what you're trying to do ?

Comment: I wanted to do something similar like this but with on click: $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#flscrolld').click(function() {
        $("#flscrolld").addClass('transition');
    
    }, function() {
        $("#flscrolld").removeClass('transition');
    });
});
in order to when I am on a new page the arrow refind his normal size. Your script works well, but I wanted to know when I clicked on the arrow it reduces its size and then refind his size automatilly without clicking one more time on it. Do you think it is possible ? Don't know if I'm clear.

Comment: Uhm, no that's not really possible, at least not in the way you're describing it. You could however use a timer, and reset the arrow after a timed delay, or use the mouseleave event to reset the arrow when the mouse leaves, or any number of other possibilities.

Comment: ok thank you very much adeneo for all these advices. I really appreciate your help.